# Drawing multiple objects from list (PyGame)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to python and trying to create a boid clone for a university course.

```
#the class
class Boid:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.pos = Vector2D(random.randrange(400), random.randrange(400))
        self.rad = 20   
        self.speed = Vector2D(-4, -4)

    def draw(self):
        py.draw.circle(self.screen, (255,50,50), (self.pos.x, self.pos.y), self.rad)

# adding objects to a list
self.boid = Boid(self.screen)
self.boid1 = Boid(self.screen)
self.boid2 = Boid(self.screen)
self.boidlist = [self.boid, self.boid1, self.boid2]

#in the game loop, drawing from list
for boid in boidlist:
    boid.draw()
```

As i understand, it currently just draws the first object thrice, and not boid(1), boid(2), etc. I tried doing something like:

```
for i in range(3):
    boid(i).draw()
```

But i can't figure out how to format it to work without error. 
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full traceback. Do you have the instantiation code inside of another class?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes the instantiation code is inside a game main class itself, but i managed to get it working with C._'s solution with some tweaking.

Comment: You should still post the complete example. It looks like all you had to do was to change `boidlist` to `self.boidlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood how to create and instantiate a class :

By typing :

```
self.boid = Boid(self.screen)
self.boid1 = Boid(self.screen)
self.boid2 = Boid(self.screen)
```

I think you want to create 3 instances of Boid, and have their screen argument be `screen`. To do so :

```
boid = Boid(screen) # 'self.' is only when you create the class
boid1 = Boid(screen)
boid2 = Boid(screen)
```

Final fixed code :

## adding objects to a list

```
boid = Boid(screen) # 'self.' is only when you create the class
boid1 = Boid(screen)
boid2 = Boid(screen)

boidlist = [boid, boid1, boid2]

#in the game loop, drawing from list
for boid in boidlist: # This should now work correctly
    boid.draw()
```